# Showing continuity of $g(x, y)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Let the domain be $y^2 \leq \frac{x}{3}$.

$g(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^3}{y^2} \left (\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y^2 + x} \right ) & y \neq 0\\
0 & y = 0
\end{cases} $

I want to show $g$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$.

We have $|g(x, y) - g(0,0)| = \frac{x^3}{y^2} \left ( \sqrt{y^2 + x} - \sqrt{x} \right )$.

Fix some $\epsilon > 0$.

Now, I want to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $x^2 + y^2 < \delta$ $\implies $ $\frac{x^3}{y^2} \left ( \sqrt{y^2 + x} - \sqrt{x} \right ) < \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\frac{x^3}{y^2} \left ( \sqrt{y^2 + x} - \sqrt{x} \right )|=|\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y^2+x}}| \leq |x|^{\frac{5}{2}}$

So the limit of the function at zero is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Write your term as $$\frac{x^3}{y^2}\frac{x+y^2-x}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y^2+x}}$$

Comment: It should be $\frac{x^3}{y^2}\frac{x+y^2-x}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y^2+x}} = \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y^2 + x}}$.

Comment: Yes it should be,thank you!